# is it possible to exec parameterized stored procedure without input in sql

Tags: sql

> Create a sp with a parameter

```
Create Procedure dbo.FetchStudentList_SP(@dpname varchar(100))
AS
Begin
    Select s.Name,d.name,d.fees,d.staff as Department 
    From Student s With(Nolock)
    full outer Join DepartMent d With(Nolock) On s.deptid = d.Id where d.name like ('%'+@dpname+'%')
End
```

> execute an sp with some value

Exec FetchStudentList_SP 'cs'

> if i did not give any value on execution i want to see below code
>   execute

```
  Select s.Name,d.name,d.fees,d.staff as Department 
    From Student s With(Nolock)
    full outer Join DepartMent d With(Nolock) On s.deptid = d.Id
```

> Any one can u please say is it possible ? if possible tell me how?
>
> Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 1):

If you can't modify the procedure, then try passing empty string when calling the procedure.

Something like this.

```
Exec FetchStudentList_SP '';
```

It will execute the query like,

```
Select s.Name,d.name,d.fees,d.staff as Department 
    From Student s With(Nolock)
    full outer Join DepartMent d With(Nolock) On s.deptid = d.Id where d.name like ('%%')
```

and there will no effect of the where condition But if will not return the rows that are having d.name as null.

Comment: Thanks bro this is exactly what i want.   thanks a lot

Comment: it's work "  Exec FetchStudentList_SP 'cs' " but at the same time  i want to execute "  Exec FetchStudentList_SP "  what can i do?

Comment: what do you mean by at the same time?

Comment: " Exec FetchStudentList_SP 'cs'   this querry will be show that value only.            and also  i want to execute same procedure         Exec FetchStudentList_SP        to view all the datas in table

Comment: Probably not an issue here, but this answer won't return values where d.name is null.

Comment: thanks @DeanOC I thought that there is no null value in the d.name.